# Meteor: startup and data loading

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Because findOne is returning undefined for some data, I tried to set up a Session variable like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  Session.set('drawingsLoaded', false);
})

Deps.autorun(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('allDrawings', function(){  
    Session.set('drawingsLoaded', true);    
    console.log(Session.get('drawingsLoaded'))
  });
```

Console logs true. But when I interactively enter

```
Session.get('drawingsLoaded')
```

it's returning false.

I have no idea why and so my data is not displaying probably because of this. I am very confused why this is returning false even though I did not set drawingsLoaded anywhere else other than startup

Answer (score 0):

If that is your actual code, maybe the `ready`-callback passed to subscribe is called before the callback passed to `Meteor.startup`?